# select values from a list after a matching condition

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I've a list of data and want to get values after a matching keyword from another list and append it to a dictionary. it should run until the next keyword is matched and added to a new dictionary.

```
a = ['Experience',
 'Software Engineer',
 'EY',
 'Sep 2018 - Present',
 'Education',
 'xyz College',
 'Bachelor of Technology - BTech, Computer Science',
 '2014 - 2017',
 'Licenses',
 'The Joy of Computing using Python ',
 'NPTEL',
 'Issued Jan 2020']

b = ['Experience', 'Education', 'Licenses']
```

Expected result:

```
c = 
    {'Experience':['Software Engineer','EY', 'Sep 2018 - Present']}, 
    {'Education':['xyz College','Bachelor of Technology - BTech, Computer Science','2014 - 2017']}, 
     {'Licenses':
     ['The Joy of Computing using Python ','NPTEL','Issued Jan 2020']}
```

```
for i in a:

    j = a.index(i)
    k = 1
    while i in b:
        c[i].append(a[j+1])
        if i == a[k]:
            k+=1
            break
        else:
            j+=1
```

but the logic is not correct and I'm stuck here.

Comment: instead of  `for i in a: j = a.index(i)`, do `for j in range(len(a)): i = a[j]`, not the bug you're having probably, but it'll save you trouble in case a list has repeated elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do a dict-comprehension and append the last element separately:

```
c = {keyword:a[a.index(keyword) + 1:a.index(next_keyword )] for keyword, next_keyword in zip(b, b[1:])}
c[b[-1]] = a[a.index(b[-1]):]

print(c)
# {'Experience': ['Software Engineer', 'EY', 'Sep 2018 - Present']}
# {'Education': ['xyz College', 'Bachelor of Technology - BTech, Computer Science', '2014 - 2017']}
# {'Licenses': ['Licenses', 'The Joy of Computing using Python ', 'NPTEL', 'Issued Jan 2020']}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using a loop (assuming you have unique keys):

```
B = set(b)
c = {}
key = None
for s in a:
    if s in B:
        key = s
        c[key] = []
    elif key is not None:
        c[key].append(s)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
{'Experience': ['Software Engineer', 'EY', 'Sep 2018 - Present'],
 'Education': ['xyz College',
  'Bachelor of Technology - BTech, Computer Science',
  '2014 - 2017'],
 'Licenses': ['The Joy of Computing using Python ',
  'NPTEL',
  'Issued Jan 2020']}
```

If you really want a list of individual dictionaries:

```
B = set(b)
c = []
key = None
for s in a:
    if s in B:
        key = s
        d = {key: []}
        c.append(d)
    elif key is not None:
        d[key].append(s)
print(c)
```

Output:

```
[{'Experience': ['Software Engineer', 'EY', 'Sep 2018 - Present']},
 {'Education': ['xyz College', 'Bachelor of Technology - BTech, Computer Science', '2014 - 2017']},
 {'Licenses': ['The Joy of Computing using Python ', 'NPTEL', 'Issued Jan 2020']}]
```

Comment: got a name error key is not defined

Comment: @Vishnuu this means that, unlike the provided example, your first item is not in the list `b`, then see update to handle such cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through a, change the variable `curr_key` to the key if it is found in list `b` and append the elements to that.

```
c = {}
curr_key = None
for string in a:
    if string in b:
        curr_key = string
    else:
        c.setdefault(curr_key, []).append(string)

print(c)
```

Output:

```
{'Experience': ['Software Engineer', 'EY', 'Sep 2018 - Present'],
 'Education': ['xyz College',
  'Bachelor of Technology - BTech, Computer Science',
  '2014 - 2017'],
 'Licenses': ['The Joy of Computing using Python ',
  'NPTEL',
  'Issued Jan 2020']}
```

Comment: I was about to update my answer with this ;)

Comment: thank you. if there was another element before the first keyword(Experience) it will add that as a separate dict. otherwise this is fine.

Comment: @Vishnuu I thought about that. But I thought makes less sense given that you need the key first to append the values to. What should happen to the values if there are other elements before the first keyword?

Comment: It should be skipped. Only the values present in the b list should form dict

Answer (score 0):

I modified the variable names for better understanding:

```
for keyword in b:
    c[keyword] = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] == keyword:
            c[keyword].append(a[i+1])
            c[keyword].append(a[i+2])
            c[keyword].append(a[i+3])
```

Comment: "*it should run until the next keyword is matched*" -> this doesn't meet the requirement